# X509_CRL_verify seg faults

Tags: openssl

I loaded a CA certificate and then loaded a CRL file 
Now i wanted to verify that CRL is actually from that CA.
So I am using libcrypto API X509_CRL_Verify 
I created a valid X509_CRL *crl object 
and now called

```
X509_CRL_verify(crl,X509_get_pubkey(ca_cert)
```

but it get crashed at this point

Can anyone point what could be issue ? CRL is valid, public key is also valid

I have loaded following Algorithms

```
ERR_load_crypto_strings();
ERR_load_BIO_strings(); 
OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers();
OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
```

Comment: Can you pls post inside which internal function it crashes and the callstack? You can use a debugger which should help you in solving the problem.